# Consume link events on jxbrowser

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, jxbrowser

I want to catch and consume (prevent redirection) link events on the teamdev's **jxbrowser**. Suppose the content is

```
<a href="testlink">link</a>
```

When the user clicks the link, I want to be informed that the user has clicked the link and get the URL, but I do not allow the page change (link should be consumed).

The problem is, the links in the quotes of the anchor tag do not start with any protocol (**http:**// or **https:**// and do not end with any .html or etc). For example the link is in the form of:

`<a href="foo">link<a>`

and we want when user clicks on the link, we get informed that the clicked string is **foo**. I know, the links in this a tag are not valid and not well formed due to the standarts, but the contents are generated by using some specific busines rules and then set to the JxBrowser. And we can not change the way the links are created.

With the example below, we get *about:blank* for the url, which is not the desired info. If we change to

```
<a href="http://foo">link</a>
```

then it works fine but we can not modify the links (content) as I have mentioned before.

```
browser.addLoadListener(new LoadListener () {
    public void onStartLoadingFrame(StartLoadingEvent arg0) {
         System.out.println("link click occured " + arg0.getValidatedURL());
         arg0.getBrowser().stop();

    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

LoadHandler allows you to handle any activity related to loading. Using LoadHandler you can determine the load type and cancel any load events. Here is an example:

```
browser.setLoadHandler(new DefaultLoadHandler() {
    @Override
    public boolean onLoad(LoadParams params) {
        if (params.getType() == LoadType.LinkClicked) {
            System.out.println("Link clicked: " + params.getURL());
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: works only for links starting with http://. onLoad not triggered for <a href="foo">link.. For the links starting with http I can also use the LoadListener

Comment: I solved the problem temporarily by replacing <a href="foo" with <a href= " h t t p : / / jxbrowser /  foo using regexp, catching the url and discarding the h t t p : / / jxbrowser / prefix and having the foo string back.

Comment: @benchpresser, in case you're loading an HTML you should specify a base URL for the links on the page, so that LoadHandler would be able to catch clicks on them:
`browser.loadHTML(new LoadHTMLParams("html", "UTF-8", "http://some-base-url/"));`